# Keyboard Keys Not Apearring;

Tags: android, kotlin, keyboard

[image: keyboard shown like this]How can I resolve the issue of the keyboard not appearing correctly when entering text into an EditText view in my Android Kotlin project? I'm unsure if this is an error in my Android project or a problem with my phone, as the issue doesn't occur on other phones.

Specifically, when I click on the comment section in my app, the keyboard fails to appear, but when I close and reopen the app, the keyboard appears as expected.

Can someone provide suggestions on how to troubleshoot this issue? Thank you.

Comment: The keyboard is a separate app, so whatever's going on in its window is down to the keyboard app, not your app! I guess it's *possible* that if you're not specifying an input type (https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/keyboard-input/style) the keyboard isn't displaying the basic default layout, so you could try that. That still shouldn't happen though - if it's not the the stock keyboard that came with the phone, maybe test with that one